# BeautifulSoup not working when scraping password protected site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a password-protected website using requests and BeautifulSoup, but I can't seem to get logged in. Although the status code is 200, the only thing that can be extracted is an error message saying: "Unfortunately, there is a critical error. Try refreshing the page or contact support." (translated)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

URL = 'https://www.orderchamp.com'
LOGIN_ROUTE = '/nl/auth/login'
HEADERS = {
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36',
              'origin': URL,
              'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE,
}

s = requests.session()

xsrf_token = s.get(URL).cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']

login_payload = {
    "_method": "post",
    "_token": str(xsrf_token),
    "return": "",
    "populate_hash": "",
    "populate_hash_email": "",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remember": "1"
}

login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req.status_code)

cookies = login_req.cookies

soup = bs(s.get(URL + "/nl/listings/kids-baby/nursery-room-decor").text, 'html.parser')
test = soup.find('div')
print(test)'
```

This is the output:

```
200
<div id="gql-critical-error-message" style="display:none">
    Helaas is er een kritieke fout opgetreden. Probeer de pagina te vernieuwen of neem contact op met de ondersteuning.
</div>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @Echo, Thank you for your response, however that didn't seem to work. I tried using the payload variable you suggested like this: login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=payload). However, the status code changed to 419 with the same critical error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to login to a website, your browser sends a POST request, the credentials are usually sent as JSON. try to import json and dump your login_payload into a json.

```
import json

login_payload = {
    "_method": "post",
    "_token": str(xsrf_token),
    "return": "",
    "populate_hash": "",
    "populate_hash_email": "",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remember": "1"
}

payload = {'data': json.dumps(login_payload)}
```